# Would Angels be able to dye their wings?

Tags: internal-consistency, culture, avian, angels

On Earth, hair has become little more than a tool of identity, and many people around the world have taken to dying their hair various colors to go with their style.

Let's say I have a species of angels *(the feasibility of which existing is not in this questions' scope)*, would they be able to dye their feathers different colors?

To follow up on this question, would they still be able to fly? How much would their flight be hindered? If they could not, how close can they get?

Comment: By angels, I take it you mean flying humans with wings? Because if you're talking about angels as understood by major monotheist religions today, they are pure spirits and their wings are just metaphorical... so they can't die their wings, nor their hair.

Comment: @PedroGabriel I mean humans with wings

Comment: @PedroGabriel Angels did appear to have a physical body in several biblical passages. Abraham fed them in Gen 18:8, Jacob wrestled with an angel Gen 32:22-32, etc. the question not answered in the Bible is whether these manifestations are actual physical beings, and simply a physical manifestation of of a pure spiritual being

Comment: Given that humans with wings cannot fly using known physics, you're into magic. So they can do whatever you want.

Comment: Most dyes will add almost zero weight, the amount of pigment involved is usually minimal. What if they changed color based on what they ate, like flamingos which are pure white naturally and only pink because of eating shrimp.

Comment: @GaryWalker: Good points.

Comment: @Schwern I thought I wrote the reality of angels was out of the scope of the question, but I must have forgotten to, I'll edit it in.

Comment: @TrEs-2b You can have flying humanoid angels, that's fine, but we don't know how they fly. If we don't know how they fly, we don't know how dieing their feathers would affect their flight. Either it's magic flight and you can do what you like, or you have to explain how they fly. It doesn't have to be known physics, but there has to be a reality to check.

Comment: The dyes would only hamper the angels if we knew how they fly. So without the "reality of angels" your question is Primarily Opinion Based.

Comment: You can dye feathers on live birds. Lord Berners used to dye his pigeons.

Comment: @GaryWalker - It’s true, they had physical forms (sometimes even human), but often they were just terrifying (not beatific winged humanoids). *Fear not*…even the cherubim (portrayed now as babies) were described as having *four* wings, *four* heads (three of which were of animals), feet of brass, and giving off coals and lightning! The ophanim (identified as angels in later but still ancient interpretations) looked like burning wheels. Most of them had wings, and some had a general humanoid shape, but they were generally *really scary*.

Comment: Does in your world exist any kind of dye? If so, why the heck shouldn't they? For the part if they could still fly.... If your world has no magic, they couldn't fly neither with dyed feathers nor without.... So sorry, but I had to down vote this as it appears to be a silly question fmpov.

Comment: You can't have wings on a human without magic.  There is no space on the chest and back for the new muscles

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Feathers can be dyed just like hair or skin or leather or fabric; this is really common knowledge. Feather dyeing has been practiced all over the world for a very long time. Here is photo of a Hawaiian 'ahu'ula, or feather cape, made of dyed feathers and cotton for Queen Kapi'olani in 1882:

[image]

([Photograph by Wally Gobetz](https://www.flickr.com/photos/wallyg/4825068908) on [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com); available under CC-BY-NC-ND-2.0.)

There is a [beautiful pictorial](https://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/gallery/2014/aug/06/painted-pigeons-paloma-al-aire-ricardo-cases-in-pictures) in *[The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/)* showing a Spanish sub-culture of pigeon fanciers who race their brightly colored pigeons ("The Spaniards who paint their pigeons in Day-Glo colours – in pictures", with photographs by Rio Casas, 6 August 2014); this shows that not only feather take dyes, but that dyeing their feathers doesn't affect birds' flight.

(Cannot embed pictures here because there is no indication that sharing is allowed; you must [go to the newspaper's website](https://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/gallery/2014/aug/06/painted-pigeons-paloma-al-aire-ricardo-cases-in-pictures) to see them; it is worth a click.)

The racing pigeon culture of Valencia and Murcia is discussed in "[Flying high with Spain's neon-painted racing pigeons](https://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/2014/aug/06/paloma-al-aire-ricardo-cases-photobook-spain-pigeon-racing)" by Sean O'Hanagan (same source, same date):

> *It is a mischievously drab opening shot for this surreal look at the racing pigeon culture of Valencia and Murcia in Spain, where breeders paint their birds in garish colours and release them to chase after a lone female. The pigeon that spends most time in her winged company wins.*
>
> ...
>
> *There is such local prestige attached to owning a champion bird, hence the seriousness with which they pursue their hobby. From the ground, the men follow the flight of their individual pigeons – easily recognisable by colour – urging them on and rescuing them if, as often seems to be the case, they land on treetops or tall buildings or electric wires for a breather.*

Since human-sized angels cannot possibly fly without mechanical help in Earth's atmosphere, it's moot to ask how much would their flight be hindered; it's pure fantasy anyway.

Comment: "It's moot to ask since it's fantasy" that's bunk... half of making a believable story is sticking to realism where possible... Knowing that people can dye pigeons - who can still fly when dyed- is the only answer that matters, IMO.

Comment: Those pigeons suggest that dye wouldn't make angel flight any *more* impossible than it currently is, which is useful to know.

Comment: "really common knowledge" - I for one did not know that actual flying birds were painted commonly. --- "Since human-sized angels cannot possibly fly". The concept is that some things are part of the question, and some are not, especially if the OP went to the trouble of specifying the latter. In this particular *world building* world, angels do exist, and they do fly (at least as long as their feathers are white). Doing it away with "it's pure fantasy anyway" would invalidate about 90% of all questions in this Exchange. I think the answer could be improved by removing the judgmental part.

Comment: [It](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-wales-36490552) can [happen](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-gloucestershire-37015956) accidentally. "The thing that shocked us the most was the smell. He smelled amazing, he really smelled good."

Comment: @AnoE: It is common knowledge that feathers can be dyed. It is much less common knowledge that the feathers _of live birds_ can be dyed harmlessly: that's why the bulk of the answer concentrates on the less common knowledge. It is important to emphasize that since human-sized animals cannot fly in Earth's atmosphere without mechanical help anyway, it makes no sense to discuss how would their flight capabilities be affected by dyeing their wings. It is always useful to make clear what's the boundary between reality and fiction. At least I like to think so.

Answer (score 2):

The dye will probably alter the texture of feathers' surface, wich can decrease or increase their performances depending the nature of the dye.

This mean angel would probably use dye if their wings are not already perfect, not only for aesthetic purposes, but also for performance.